# Magento Products are not listed on fronend

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I downloaded a old magento site and installed it on my local server.
My admin panel is working perfect but products are not listed in frontend.
Links on the front end page are also not working.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you 'downloaded an old magento site', do you mean that you just copied down the folder structure? 
If so, this won't have copied the product database, which is an entirely  separate entity to the php/js/html/css that comprises the file structure.

Comment: Thanks for responding..... Yes i have imported the database also......I am able to add new products from admin panel ....the problem is only in frontend...

Answer (score 0):

Try reindexing and clearing the cache.  Also, did you make sure the Base urls were updated in core_config_data database table?

Comment: thanks for responding..........Yes base urls are update in database and I have also tried reindexing ad clearing cache but it's not working......